# Symfony form validation value is in array

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to handle the form field validation of a TextType field in Symfony2's form builder context.

There is a field that should explicitly be filled manually with one of two possible values ([email=all], [email=test]). It's intended to be some security feature to assure that the user is definitely aware of what he's doing next.

I'm wondering if there is a validation constraint that can be used to validate the field's input value to fit one of the two known options. Either [email=all] or [email=test]. In plain PHP i would do like so

```
function isValid($value){
    $options = array("[email=all]","[email=test]");
    return (in_array($value, $options)) ? true : false;
}
```

I'm aware that I'd build a custom validation constraint but maybe this could even be solved with Symfony standard constraints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Choice`](http://symfony.com/doc/3.0/reference/constraints/Choice.html) constraint.

An example:

```
// src/AppBundle/EntityAuthor.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    protected $gender;

    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('gender', new Assert\Choice(array(
            'choices' => array('male', 'female'),
            'message' => 'Choose a valid gender.',
        )));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly what i was looking for! Kind regards!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible!
You should use either [Callback constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) validation or [Expression constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html). That last one is the easiest and pragmatic way to go.
Consider an entity called `Task`:

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Task 
{
    protected $id;
    protected $title;  

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }   
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    //...
}
```

Now we assume the title property MUST have a **foo** or **bar** word, or whether some value (from title property) is in an defined array:

```
 # src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
    AppBundle\Entity\Task:
        properties:
            title: 
                - Expression: 
                    expression: "this.getTitle() in ['foo', 'bar']", 
                    message: "Title must be 'foo' or 'bar'!"
                - NotBlank: ~
```

So in your specific case, just swap `['foo', 'bar']` by `['[email=all]', '[email=test]']` or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not a friend of doing the validation on the entity itself (no matter if via yml or annotation). Is there a way to set it as constraint directly in the form builder class?